# What would the statement "You over there!" be called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If someone was to shout "You over there!" to get the attention of a friend, for instance, what would this statement be called?

Would it be a declarative because "You" is over there, but then is it an exclamative because you are exclaiming the statement to get the friend's attention... or is it something else entirely?

Comment: It's not a statement. It's certainly not a sentence. It's a deictic phrasal vocative (using the [Collins COBUILD AED](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vocative)).

Comment: I'd call it a "hail".

Comment: It's not really an implicit sentence, even. It's an interjected noun phrase. In most uses that I can think of, the rest of the sentence follows: e.g. "You over there! State your business." is really one sentence where the noun phrase is the subject.

Answer (score 3):

'Hey!', for instance, is an interjection.

The whole construction here is an interjection used to get someone's attention.  Depending on tone, it could be considered either informal or rude.

> An **interjection** is
>
> used especially to call attention or to express interrogation,
>   surprise, or exultation.

See [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hey).

*You* is a **vocative**, used to address the addressee.  The pronoun *you* is a substitute for the name or the title of the person addressed, as in

Hey, Joanna!

or

Waiter!

> Definition of vocative from Merriam Webster Dictionary:
>   ...
>
> 2 [of a word or word group]:  marking the one addressed (as mother in
>   “mother, come here”)
>   [https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocative]

Answer (score -2):

Certainly, there is no **verb** that shows tense in that "**sentence**", so it could not be considered to be such. It sounds like a command with an explicit subject.

I would say you may get different opinions regarding it being a "**reduced sentence with a verb implied**" or simply a "**phrase containing a subject implying command**".

These questions normally draw many different perspectives; however, this note from *Longman English Grammar book* acknowledges a sentence as:

> When we speak, we often say things like *All right! Good! Want any help?*
>   These are 'complete units of meaning', but they are not real sentences. A simple sentence is a complete unit of meaning which contains a subject and a verb,
>   followed, if necessary, by other words which make up the meaning

So, there will probably be two different points of view, and I believe that your "**sentence**" may be seen as a "*complete sentence with verbs cleaned up*" - **You go over there!**

[Longman English Book](https://english4u.com.vn/Uploads/files/Longman%20English%20Grammar%20Practice.pdf)

Comment: 'If someone was to shout "You over there!" to get the attention of a friend', **not** as a command ("You ... over there!")

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed this part.

Anyway, I can't think of it as not being a command; there is a *subject* and an exclamation **(!)**

Comment: 'Command' means 'give an authoritative or peremptory order.' ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/command)). 'You ... over there!' (short for 'You ... get over there!') is a command, but 'You over there!' is a (shouted) identifying vocative, like 'You with the red hat on!' No command (though one might well follow).  'You over there! Well played, man!' shows that a command _needn't_ be involved at all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Both ways could be interpreted.

Comment: No they couldn't; there needs to be a signalled separation shown in print  in the case of a command (whether by the inclusion of a dash, an ellipsis, or by the use of two sentence-substitutes [You! Over there!] ). This corresponds to a pause in speech. Note that I'm not the only one to consider your answer (specifically, the second half) unhelpful.